# SvelteKit OAuth user specific encryption

Tags: database, postgresql, encryption, svelte, sveltekit

I am really not sure how I should handle this, so I will just ask here for what you recommend me to do.

I use Lucia, and my application runs on my own Virtual Private Server. On the vps, there is a postgres database, and there are all users stored, their own private posts, etc.

So that means, I can read it inside of the database since I am the server owner.

How do you suggest me to handle encryption for the column posts for example. Only the specific user can see their posts and it is invisible for me because I do not have the key and thus see nothing in the db because of encryption.

I guess I could say users automatically get a 50 or so character long key that they should store in a secure location, and each time they access the application, they need to enter this key (could also be stored in local storage so not always necessary)

My problem with this is that it is very inconvenient and probably quite annoying for a lot of users. Ideally, they would not have to do anything. Their posts are just encrypted in the database and then automatically decrypted with their specific account without providing some secret key.

For oauth a user does not need to provide any real secrets though, since the authentication is handled on for example github or googles servers and everything else complex. Otherwise, I would have said I could encrypt the posts with the users password as key (could also be problematic since they can be the same for multiple users)

Do you guys have any suggestions for what I could do in this case?

I am not sure what I can do to achieve this, so there is nothing I have done yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you store the users password as a hash in the database, the best solution would be to derive the encryption key through the users hash, using key deviation algorithms such as PBKDF2HMAC, and once the user is logged in, use their hash to decrypt the user data. Make sure that the database is not exposed to the client, or there could be security implications.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).